# Mysql update with data from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables buffer_details and stock. I want to update the stock table with data from the buffer details table.

```
CREATE TABLE `buffer_details` (  `Ref` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,   `Reference_produit` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,  `Qte` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`Reference_produit`) USING BTREE ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE `stock` (`Reference` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `qte` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',  PRIMARY KEY (`Reference`) USING BTREE ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I tried this but it does not work , I am using Mysql. Please note that it is Qte = Qte + (buffer_details.Qte)

```
Update (select * from buffer_details) AS D1,stock set stock.qte = stock.qte + D1.Qte WHERE stock.Reference = D1.Reference_produit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the update-join syntax:

```
UPDATE stock s
JOIN   buffer_details d1 ON s.reference = d1.reference_produit
SET    s.qte = s.qte + d1.qte
```